# Equivalent of bash -x for zsh

Tags: zsh

Is there a way of having the command I just entered echoed onto the screen after entering?

Ex:

```
$ echo hello
+ echo hello
hello
```

I know this can be done with `bash -x` but I could not find the equivalent in the zsh manual.

Comment: Did you try `zsh -x`?

Comment: did you try zsh -x? The -x works for sh as well.

Comment: I tried it but it caused my terminal to output a bunch of random stuff so I assumed it wasn't right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-x` (or `-o xtrace`) option works in `zsh` too. That comes from the Bourne shell in the late 70s and is supported by all Bourne like shells. From `man zshoptions` / `info zsh xtrace`:

> ```
> XTRACE (-x, ksh: -x)
>     Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.  The
>     output is preceded by the value of $PS4, formatted as described
>     in the section EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES in zshmisc(1).
> ```

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh -x

echo hello
```

and an example run:

```
$ /tmp/ex.sh
+/tmp/ex.sh:3> echo hello
hello
```

Like in `bash` / `ksh`, it can be enabled with `set -x` or `set -o xtrace` and disabled afterwards with `set +x` or `set +o xtrace`. It's also possible to enable tracing on a per-function basis with `functions -t myfunction`.

Beware that in interactive shells, if you've enabled a number of fancy plugins or advanced completion, then you'll also see the tracing corresponding to the execution of those which may affect your interactive shell experience.

Comment: Would this be set with `setopt XTRACE` or `setopt -x` in `.zshrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Addendum the correct answer by Andy Dalton, relative to comment by Will …

> I tried it but it caused my terminal to output a bunch of random stuff so I assumed it wasn't right.

For zsh, `add-zsh-hook -d precmd update_terminal_cwd` can be used reduce trace `XTRACE` clutter in Apple's Terminal app.

**TL;DR**

In the case of Apple's Terminal app, there is an addition of `update_terminal_cwd()` which runs at each prompt update.

The `update_terminal_cwd` call is also shown in, and adds clutter to, the 'set -x' `XTRACE`.

```sh
username@hostname ~ % echo hello
# +-zsh:2> echo hello
# hello
# +update_terminal_cwd:5> local url_path=''                                                                                         
# +update_terminal_cwd:10> local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_COLLATE=C LC_ALL='' LANG=''
# +update_terminal_cwd:11> i = 1
# 
# … <snip>
# 
# +update_terminal_cwd:22> printf '\e]7;%s\a' #file://hostname.local/Users/username
```

*/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal*

```sh
update_terminal_cwd() {
# Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL, including
# the host name to disambiguate local vs. remote paths.

# … <snip>

printf '\e]7;%s\a' "file://$HOSTNAME$url_path"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd${PROMPT_COMMAND:+; $PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

Bash workaround: `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` or modify `PROMPT_COMMAND` to not use `update_terminal_cwd`.

*/etc/zhrc_Apple_Terminal*

```sh
update_terminal_cwd() {
# Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL, including
# the host name to disambiguate local vs. remote paths.

    # Percent-encode the pathname.
    local url_path=''
    {
      # … <snip>
    }

printf '\e]7;%s\a' "file://$HOST$url_path"
}

# Register the function so it is called at each prompt.
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd update_terminal_cwd
```

Zsh workaround can be done with a `-d` delete from the `precmd` zsh-hook:

```sh
### `-L` list
user@host ~ % add-zsh-hook -L
# typeset -g -a zshexit_functions=( shell_session_update )
# typeset -g -a precmd_functions=( update_terminal_cwd )

user@host ~ % add-zsh-hook -d precmd update_terminal_cwd

user@host ~ % add-zsh-hook -L                           
# typeset -g -a zshexit_functions=( shell_session_update )

user@host ~ % set -x
user@host ~ % echo hello
# +-zsh:8> echo hello
# hello

user@host ~ % set +x; add-zsh-hook -L
# typeset -g -a zshexit_functions=( shell_session_update )
```